# TableView in ViewController instead of TableViewController for Datan| Parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview

I am using Swift with Parse.com. I have a bridging header so I presume that I can use objective-C within the swift project, but I get errors sometimes, so I want to make sure that I am using the two languages correctly within the same project.

I remain unclear how I can use `tableView` to load information from Parse instead of using the `tableViewController` for added customization. I would like to be able to use the needed methods within the view controller that contains the `tableView` object, and reload that information to populate that element.

I need to an update on the requirements of proper classes and if I need to subclass, and how. I have generated my own class for the view controller and connected the `tableView` object, but I remain unclear how I can call the methods from a normal `tableviewcontroller`, or if I can simply place the needed methods within the view controller. I am learning about the PFClasses and which ones are needed for the functions that are required.

I currently remain unclear about the communication of the delegates, datasource, and other related items in this arrangement. I am completing project. I am still new to objective-C and have not memorized all of the methods and such, so I am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a plain `UIViewController` and have a manual `UITableView` instead of using a `UITableViewController`. If you do this, you need to make sure that your `UIViewController` implements the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

If you are using IB, you also need to make sure you hook up your custom `UITableView` class to the proper outlets; or you can create your views in code. That's up to you.

Now for parse specific data, what you can do is you can process your parse.com data in a variety of ways; in response to a UI gesture, when the table loads, or in the background. Either way, once you have the parse data loaded, you just need to make sure your `UITableView` responds correctly in `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

If you get started and have specific questions, feel free to ask more. But in short, yes, it is possible. I actually prefer this over using `UITableViewController` because it gives me more flexibility. I in general to not use IB.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I will process with a sample in a few moments. I am working on queries at the moment, and let you know how it works. I didn't see any problems with it in general, and the internet did not have much information to use otherwise using the UITableViewController.

Comment: I will update the delegate and the datasource of the tableview to the view controller. Do I need to add any additional information to the view controller class, such as specify delegate protocols? Can I simply copy and paste the needed methods into the view controller and update them as needed?

Comment: If your view controller implements the delegate and datasource, you will need to paste the needed methods into the view controller. What I normally do is go to the Apple reference for the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` and copy the Swift/Objective-C function definitions that I need, and then I implement them.